# Pointer difference when initializing embedded structs

Tags: pointers, go, composition, embedding

I am playing around with struct embedding and have a problem with keeping the same reference to the embedded struct.

Try out [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/T1AkCqbkQz) and see that there are two different pointer addresses to `*strings.Reader`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Base struct {
    reader *strings.Reader
}

func NewBase() *Base {
    r := strings.NewReader("hello")

    fmt.Printf("document: %#+v\n\n", &r)
    return &Base{r}
}

func (b *Base) Check() {
    fmt.Printf("document: %#+v\n\n", &b.reader)

}

type Concrete struct {
    *Base
}

func NewConcrete() *Concrete {
    return &Concrete{NewBase()}
}

func main() {
    c := NewConcrete()
    c.Check()
}
```

**Why are these addresses not the same? How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking the address of the pointer, not the pointer itself.

```
func NewBase() *Base {
    r := strings.NewReader("hello")

    fmt.Printf("document: %#p\n\n", r)
    return &Base{r}
}

func (b *Base) Check() {
    fmt.Printf("document: %#p\n\n", b.reader)

}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Z9oWXFMuUu)

//edit

```
r := strings.NewReader("hello")
```

`r` is a variable holding a pointer to `strings.Reader`, `&r` is the address of the variable holding the pointer to `strings.Reader`.

```
fmt.Printf("document: %#+v\n\n", &b.reader)
```

`&b.reader` is the address of the variable `b.reader`, which is holding the pointer of the `strings.Reader` from earlier.